# How to check for differences between two lists, each having dictionaries as members of lists?

Tags: python-2.7

I have two files (old and current). I store the previous value received from client in old file (olddata.txt) and the current received value from client in cdata.txt

Example: in olddata.txt :

```
{"cdata": [{"time": "14:14:20", "cname": "client1", "sig":"somedata"}]}
```

in cdata.txt :

```
{"cdata": [
   {"time":"14:14:30" , "cname": "client1", "sig":"somedata"}, 
   {"time": "14:14:30", "cname": "client2", "sig":"somedata"}]}
```

Its stored as JSON.

I am trying to find the threshold (10seconds) for response from  client based on the previous received timestamp and currently received time stamp.

But the problem is that there are instances where initially 5 client values were sent and later only 2. In such a case i want to keep track of the previous 3 clients (threshold) who did not send their values. Also, could be the case where the new data  received from client has 6 client values and previously only 3 were sent. (Am simulating multiple clients on a single machine)

I tried this:

```
    for outloop in cdatadata:
        ccname = outloop.get("cname")
        ctime  = outloop.get("timC")
        for item in oldData:
            ocname = item.get("cname")
            otimC = item.get("timC")
            if ccname == ocname:
            ........ 
            ....
```

but it checks only for matched clients.

Apologies if its a silly question.I am new to python and list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this like so.  First get your data into a structure which keeps details for each client together.  e.g.

```
{
  "client1": {
    "new": {
      "cname": "client1", 
      "sig": "somedata", 
      "time": "14:14:30"
    }, 
    "old": {
      "cname": "client1", 
      "sig": "somedata", 
      "time": "14:14:20"
    }
  }, 
  "client2": {
    "new": {
      "cname": "client2", 
      "sig": "somedata", 
      "time": "14:14:30"
    }
  }, 
  "client3": {
    "old": {
      "cname": "client3", 
      "sig": "somedata", 
      "time": "14:14:20"
    }
  }
}
```

with a script like

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
oldnew = defaultdict(dict)

with file('olddata.txt') as f:
    for e in json.load(f)['cdata']:
        oldnew[e['cname']]['old'] = e

with file('cdata.txt') as f:
    for e in json.load(f)['cdata']:
        oldnew[e['cname']]['new'] = e

print json.dumps(oldnew,indent=2)
```

then write logic to examine the data for each client and decide what to do with the old and new data.  You could start by just making a report like

```
client____ new_______ old_______
   client1   14:14:30   14:14:20
   client2   14:14:30       None
   client3       None   14:14:20
```

with code like

```
def val(d,*p):
    for i in p: d = d.get(i,{})
    return None if d == {} else d

print "client____ new_______ old_______"
for cname, c in oldnew.items():
    otime, ntime = val(c,'old','time'), val(c,'new','time')
    print "%(cname)10s %(ntime)10s %(otime)10s" % locals()
```

Then improve it until the logic you want is clear to you.